# Sine and Cosine functions and modulo

Tags: functions

Given some positive values $a_0,a_1,\cdots , a_{n-1}$ and an integer $n$, i want to   "build" a function $f$ such that for integer $k$ we have that :

$ f(k) = a_{k \mod n}$

for instance $a_0=\pi,a_1=e,a_2= 1.5$ and $n=3$ so $f(4) = a_{4\mod 3} = a_1 = e$

I want $f$ to be continues function over $\mathbb{R}$, so i don't want to break $f$ into "cases", but rather i would like to use $\sin , \cos$ functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Define a function on $[0,n]$ such that $f(0)=a_0,f(1)=a_1,\dots, f(n)=a_0.$ Extend it to get a periodic function.

Comment: @mfl how is that ? do i need sine function or cosine ?

Comment: Upss. You want to have an explicit function that doesn't break into cases. Ok. Use Trigonometric interpolation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation)